# Dependency isn't recognized in Intellij

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, testng

I have a problem with my MAVEN.I have added this dependency com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JSR310 in the pom.xml and I wanted to import it in one class.But this dependency isn't imported.It seems that the dependency in the pom isn't recognized.How can I resolve this issue, please?

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- CSV -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: try to make a maven build in your IDE, this should download the jars and add them to your project's classpath.

Comment: Can you add to your question a snippet of your pom.xml with jsr310 dependency?

Comment: Could you show ust the pom, plz. Maybe the dependency's scope isnt't `compile`. Have you tried `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: No.I haven't tried this.This is the part of the pom where the dependency is declared:                                                                                         
        <dependency>             
                  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>   
        </dependency>
        <!-- CSV -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: The   jsr310 dependency is here:                                                     <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: Thank you Alexander.But when I tried  mvn dependency:tree i got this error:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JSR310Module

Comment: Paste your POM.xml in the main post.

Comment: I have done it.you can ckeck it

Answer (score 0):

Did you add maven support to project?

1. enable auto-import in settings|
2. try mvn clean-install in console
3. in tab "maven projects" try to "reimport all maven projects"

Comment: I think that the auto-import configuration is already configured in my IDE.The mvn clean install without tests:mvn clean install -Denv=local -DskipTests is displaying build success.Ihave tried to make "reimport all maven projects" but the dependency still not taken into account

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to "Re-import All Maven Projects"? It's the blue circular button on the "Maven Projects" tab.